# Java Null pointer exception in sending a hashmap from a server to a client

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream

I write a server/client code that sends a hashmap using `ObjectOutputStream` from server to client. I write also an `update` function that is invoked every 50 milliseconds to send that hashMap.

```
public void update() {
    try {
        //oos is an objectoutput stream
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> hash = new HashMap<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < objects.size(); j++)
            hash.put(objects.get(j).toString(), judge.getInfo(objects.get(j)));
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            oos[i].writeObject("money#"
                    + judge.getMoney(player[i].getTeam()));
            //System.out.println(judge.getMoney(player[i].getTeam()));
            oos[i].writeObject("time#" + judge.getTime());
            if(hash==null)
                System.out.println("HASH"+hash);
            if(oos[i]==null)
                System.out.println("nulllllllll");
            oos[i].writeObject(hash); //*****line 229 of Game.java ******/
            oos[i].flush();

            //oos[i].reset();
            //System.out.println(hash.size());
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();

    } catch (MahyariseExceptionBase meb) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

Sometimes above code throws an exception like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1500)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
     at network.Game.update(Game.java:229)
     at judge.judge.next50milis(judge.java:403)
     at judge.judge$1.run(judge.java:421)
     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
```

That HashMap has a small size, also if the `update` function invokes every 1000 ms we can see the above exception being thrown.

Following the client side code:

```
    Thread read = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            Object a=null;
            try {
                if (socket.isConnected() && !socket.isClosed()) {
                    a = inputStream.readObject();
                    if (a != null)
                        analyze(a);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                loose();
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: @kruemel HashMaps may contain null, and so serialization must be able to handle it.

Comment: You aren't using isConnected() in a valid way here. It doesn't tell you anything about the state of the connection, only of the socket itself.

Comment: @EJP yes i don't really know enough about checking connection between client and server. i would be happy if you could help me with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the source code on Grepcode to try to figure out what the stacktrace means.  The line numbers make sense for the [Java 8 version of the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java/), but not older versions.

But beyond that, it is hard to say.  It looks like the `currContext` internal field in the `ObjectOutputStream` object is `null`, but my reading of the code immediately preceding line 1500 is that it can't happen!

Unless ...

... there two threads attempting to use the same `ObjectOutputStream` without synchronizing properly.  Bear in mind that `ObjectOutputStream` is not documented as being thread-safe, and doesn't synchronize internally.

So that's my theory for what is causing the NPE.

Comment: That's the same conclusion I've reached after reading this class in three versions. Additionally, I'm suspicious w.r.t. to the way the short term scheduling ("every N ms") is handled, and whether one such task is complete before the next one is started.

Comment: I just had the same problem and it is definitely a thread safety issue.